# How to keep contents in variable between the executions (Mojo)

Tags: java

Need some help!

I need to keep the variable contents between executions (Mojo). Is this possible?

This is the variable that I need to keep the content:

```
@Mojo (name = "genschema", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.COMPILE)
public class JsonSchemaGen extends AbstractMojo
{
::
::
private static final Map<String, ArrayList<String>> hookingElements = new HashMap<>();
```

This example of my pom.xml

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>com.xxx.yyy</groupId>
                <artifactId>test</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <schema>test.json</schemaFile>
                          ::
                          ::
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <schemaFile>teste1.json</schemaFile>
                          ::
                          ::
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <schemaFile>test2.json</schemaFile>
                          ::
                          ::
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to keep the variable contents between executions

The way to do this is to save the value in a more permanent location such as a file or database.